# bcp randomly fails in a batch of 100+ jobs

Tags: python, sql-server, multithreading, bcp

I have a Python program that generates over 300 files and uses `bcp` to move them to MSSQL. There is a high level of concurrency as about 21 files are being generated and bcp'd in at the same time. Here is the critical part of the program:

```
    cmd = ['bcp', self.bcptbl, 'IN', outfile, '-f', 'bcpfmt.fmt', '-m1', '-U', uid, '-S', self.srv, '-P', pwd]
    subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Three batch threads go at a time, 7 sub-threads each, so 21 concurrent processes. At a random file `bcp` fails with error:

`[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file`

The error might have something to do with the way I create file before BCP is invoked:

```
with open(outfile, 'a') as outf:
    proc = Popen('ext_prog.exe', stdin=PIPE, stdout=outf, stderr=PIPE)
    _, err = proc.communicate(input='\n'.join(patterns).encode('latin1'))
```

Something tells me that the file handle is not released by the external program, even though file open and close is seemingly handled by me.

This is not a typical error, as permissions, folders, paths, etc are all set up correctly, since it copies 80 ~ 150 files successfully before failing.

BCP call in the code above failed frequently until I inserted the following check before the bcp call:

```
@staticmethod
def wait_file_is_ready(outfile):
    try:
        with open(outfile, 'r'):
            print("File {} is ready for reading".format(outfile))
    except BaseException as e:
        print("File {} is not ready: {}".format(outfile, e))
```

My reasoning is that Windows does not mark the file as closed in time so opening and closing it helps. This fixed 99% of errors but with the massive job I got today it came back to haunt me.

Things I tried to recover from error:

- Adding a 1 hour sleep before re-running same bcp command - fails
- Making a copy of the input file and re-running bcp command - fails
- Running the BCP command manually from command line always works

More detailed code excerpt:

```
MAX_THREADS = 7

def start_batch(self):
    ts = []
    self.patternq = queue.Queue()
    self.bcptbl = '"tempdb.dbo.outtbl_{}"'.format(randint(0,1E15))
    for thread_no in range(MAX_THREADS):
        tname = "thread_{:02}_of_{}".format(thread_no, MAX_THREADS)
        t = Thread(name=tname, target=self.load, args=(thread_no,))
        t.start()
        ts.append(t)

    for t in ts:
        t.join()

def load(self, thread_no):
    outfile = "d:\\tmp\\outfile_{}_{:02}.temp".format(
        randint(0,1E15), thread_no)
    try:
        os.unlink(outfile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    while True:
        try:
            patterns = self.patternq.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            break
        with open(outfile, 'a') as outf:
            proc = Popen('ext_prog.exe', stdin=PIPE, stdout=outf, stderr=PIPE)
            _, err = proc.communicate(input='\n'.join(patterns).encode('latin1'))

    cmd = ['bcp', self.bcptbl, 'IN', outfile, '-f', 'bcpfmt.fmt', '-m1', '-U', uid, '-S', self.srv, '-P', pwd]
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(cmd)            
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        # OK, it failed because "Unable to open BCP host data-file"
        # How can I recover from it?
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

I went around the problem by using ODBC to insert the records, slowly and carefully. That worked 2 out of 3 times. Here is the error I got on third iteration:

os.unlink(outfile)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'd:\tmp\outfile_678410328373703.temp_03'

And a feasible explanation for the error:
[Seems to be an issue long standing and a bug inherent with Windows 7](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by.1051872/)

> Found this in [MS forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/the-action-cant-be-completed-because-the-file-is/381e9f29-50a5-4fa3-b9f2-7b3389293063)
>
> Seems to be an issue long standing and a bug inherent with Windows 7.
>
> There has been no "official" statement from MS acknowledging this bug hence a patch or fix release is unlikely. Some users in the thread above have offered "fixes" but they are way too time consuming and inefficient in regards to workflow productivity. This shouldn't be an issue one has to deal with when purchasing a new OS ...